# Caching and Mysql binary logs

Tags: 8, database, caching

In my recent Drupal 8 project, we have the master-slave setup and we face binary-log files getting generated to a huge amount for every hour. On decoding these binary log files we figured out a lot of INSERT INTO statements to 'cache_render', 'cache_menu', 'cache_data' tables. But we have enabled Memcache setup at the server level and its working fine and also disabled all default Drupal caches from admin backend. 
Even after these, does the Drupal 8 by default make entries to cache related tables? Do someone faced the same before?

Comment: Can you verify Memcache is working and configured correctly to Drupal?